# IBM Worklight: publicWorkLightHostname for Active/Active Webservers

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, load-balancing, worklight-server, websphere-liberty, ibmhttpserver

Environment:

1. IBM HTTP Server 8.5 - http:81/https:91
2. Liberty Profile 8.5.5.1
3. IBM Worklight 6.2 - http:9081/https:9091

Setup has Load balancer then two IHS[Active/Active] & two Worklight Servers.

Load Balancer routes the request from the client to both IHS in Round Robin.

Each IHS points to both the Worklight servers.

In Worklight.properties,

```
publicWorkLightHostname=localhost
publicWorkLightProtocol=http
publicWorkLightPort=10080
```

What should I fill in each .war file deployment in worklight server. Load Balancer IP, Port & Protocol?

I am confused with the Active/Active Webserver's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following:

- http://ibmmobiletipsntricks.com/2014/05/26/where-do-i-specify-the-hostname-of-my-worklight-server/
- [IBM Worklight 6.1 - When are these properties used? publicWorkLightHostname/Protocol/Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793586/ibm-worklight-6-1-when-are-these-properties-used-publicworklighthostname-prot)

The `publicWorkLightHostname`, `publicWorkLightProtocol`, and `publicWorkLightPort` properties in the worklight.properties file determine:

- Where the Mobile web and desktop browser apps should connect back to.
- How the Worklight Application Center (if used) will form RESTful URLs for its own internal use.

In all cases, these hostnames should point to the externally-resolvable address of the Worklight server (in front of any load-balancers, firewalls, proxies, etc.).

Comment: So, it doesn't have any involvement in Mobile App environments .